# Angular2 unable to set HTTP header authorization

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, angular2-services

I've a service called **ProjectService**, where the following code exists:

```
..... # skip codes
getProjects(): Observable<any> {
    let url = API.MAIN_URL + '/api/project/';
    return this.http.get(url, this.requestHeaders())
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }

..... # skip codes
requestHeaders(): any {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'token ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return options;
  }
```

In my **ProjectComponent** I tried to subscribe the `getProjects()` from `ProjectService` via following code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this._projectService.getProjects().subscribe(data => {
        this.projects = data;
      },
      error => this.message = this.errorMessage(error._body));

  }
```

The problem is, whenever my `ProjectComponent` loads, my console gives me following error:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I go to my browsers network panel to see the error, it shows that

> "Authentication credentials were not provided."

means that my request doesn't have any authorization token.

I've used the [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) plugin. then added the token there like `token eaab49d1dd392bda3fb807f33e1eb296897efc79` in the `Authorization` hash value.
And it works like a charm!

Don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure `localStorage.getItem('token')` returns the value you expect?

Comment: @FredrikLundin, Yes it returns `eaab49d1dd392bda3fb807f33e1eb296897efc79`

Comment: You Probably have to wrap the header like that:    .get(url, { headers: headers })

Comment: @f.b. Tried. Not working :(

Comment: Have you imported RequestOptions from angular? I know I've had my fair share of http problems from not importing Request, RequestOptions and so on from angular

Comment: In practically every Browser you can display request details, have a look if the headers are set.

Comment: Could be that the string "token" that you put in front of your actual token is case sensitive and should be capitalized: `'Token' /* <-- HERE */  + localStorage.getItem('token'));`. Also, are you sure that shouldn't use "Bearer" instead of "token"?

Comment: @FredrikLundin, No it's `token` with "t". and also it's not `Breaer`. I've checked that in postman. 
@Namirna, `RequestOptions` is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't laugh, but I'm sure this is the most lame answer of my question above. 
I just changed the following lines:

```
let headers = new Headers();
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
```

To this:

```
const headers = new Headers();
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
```

Then It works!

Also, I'm using `Http` previously, then I switched to `HttpClientModule`. But of them are working now.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updating answer to reflect comments

This is due to your `OPTIONS` request that Angular makes. Add an additional endpoint of type `HttpOptions` that returns a status `200 OK`, also ensure that this endpoint does not require authentication.

Comment: Actually it's added. And in last portion of my question I've added that I used ModHeader to see if it works or not. And it works when I add `Authorization` with modheader manually. It's a problem from angular

Comment: Ah yes, if you use postman does the API endpoint work? The reason I'm asking is that it might be the `Options` request that is failing, you may need to add an `Options` endpoint to your API

Comment: Ok, it's your `OPTIONS` request that is failing, add an `OPTIONS` endpoint with the same URL route and return a `200` from it. Also disable authentication on that endpoint. Should sort out your issue

Comment: Could you please update your answer according to your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's help you:

```
let headers = new Headers({ *your headers* });
let options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true, headers });
```

then try

```
http.get(url, options)
```

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to create headers this way :

```
setHeaders()
{
    this.headers = new Headers
    ({
        'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
}
```

and send request method:

```
send_request_get(url: any)
{
    this.setHeaders();
    let options = new RequestOptions
    (
        {
            headers: this.headers
        }
    );

    return this.http.get(url,options )
    ...
}
```